# Xtext: Building type map while parsing

Tags: types, grammar, antlr3, xtext

In [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/), how can I build a type map (i.e. a Java map) from the type declarations in my model file? Say my model file looks like this:

```
type String { ...some definitions... }
type Foo { ...some definitions... }
```

and my Xtext grammar says:

```
DataType: 'type' name=ID '{' ... '}';
```

How can I build a map of `<String,DataType>` while the parser runs or before the template is evaluated? How can I access the map later from the Xpand template?

Note: It's 2011. Please avoid global variables (`static`).

Answer (score 1):

Hey Aaron, I am not sure what you are trying to do. But let's assume your data types are part of a model, e.g.

```
Model: "myfile" datatypes+=DataType;
DataType: "type" name=ID ...;
```

you could traverse them with Xpand like this

```
«FOREACH model.datatypes AS d»
«d.name», «d.someDefinitions»
«ENDFOREACH»
```

Comment: My implementation of TypeMap does some processing of the types. I need to be able to call `«typeMap.name(d)»` for each data type.

Comment: Or to put it another way: How do I inject the same bean into the parser and the template?

Comment: The easiest way would probably a call-out with Java-Extensions (static Java method that somehow gains access to your bean) where you configure the Java-Part before you run the generator.